# Counting nodes in General tree in python

Tags: python, tree

I have created a Tree structure that is not a binary tree and having difficulties in getting the correct node count.

```
class TreeNode(object):
  def __init__(self, name='root', children=None,Parent=[]):
    self.Name = name
    self.Parents=Parent

    self.Children = []
    if children is not None:
        for child in children:
            self.add_child(child.Name)

 def __repr__(self):
   return self.Name

 def add_child(self, node):    
  self.Children.append(node)
```

and this is the latest in what I have tried to do in order to count the number of nodes in the tree.

```
def countNodes(Tree):      

   for Child in Tree.Children:
      return countNodes(Child)+1

   return 1
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work?
EDIT: I should clarify, When I say doesn't work it gives me a completely wrong count for he number of nodes in my graph.

Comment: what is wrong ? it  is giving you a bad answer or an execution error ?

Comment: completely wrong number for the count

Comment: Beware of using lists as default arguments, eg `Parent=[]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `countNodes` function is not well. A parent node can have two childs, if you put  a `return` statement within the `for` loop, it will return on the first child count and the second child count will be missing. You need to do something like this:

```
def countNodes(Tree):      
   count = 1
   for Child in Tree.Children:
      count +=  countNodes(Child)
   return count
```

Comment: yep, thats what i was missing. thanks works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

> Just to add @levi has missed an edge case where root is None

so the modified code will be :

```
def numNodes(root):
    if root == None:
        return 0 
    node = 1
    for child in root.children:
        node = node + numNodes(child)
    return node
```